# how to get string response as a object from API in angular 9?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, api, response, error-messaging

When I call API to get particular list of data according to pass id in API that time it properly works and return object as list of data. but if API don't exist provided id in database then it returns string like in spring boot return "Sorry this id doesn't exist in our list";

So that time we can find string response via inspect by the chrome. but how can we get that string in angular so that we can show user response message from API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet. Hope that works for you.

```
returnObservableAsStringResp(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'text'
    }
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL , requestOptions);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks dear for your help but I found another solution for this issue.it seems better for me. this one  (data: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            alert(data.error.text);
            console.warn(data.error.text);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
public call(id: any) {
    this.Student = [];
    this.httpClient.getfriends(id).subscribe((respo) => {
        for (const d of (respo as any)) {
            this.Student.push({
                id: d.id,
                name: d.name,
                profilepic: d.profilepic,
                address: d.address,
                mobile: d.mobile,
                isfriend: d.isfriend
            });
        }
        console.warn("resp", respo)
    },
        (data: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            alert(data.error.text);
            console.warn(data.error.text);
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: If API doesn't exist provided id in the database, then it returns an error as `Sorry this id doesn't exist in our list`. Am I correct?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).